# console.log JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

**Problem**

I'm trying to log the data returned from a JSON call, and `console.log(jsonData)` doesn't seem to be working.

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#users li a:first-child").click(function() {

        var id = this.href.replace(/.*=/, "");
        this.id = "delete_link_" + id;

        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?"))
        {
            $.getJSON("delete.php?ajax=true&id=" + id, function(data) {
                console.log(data.success);
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

**Returned by `delete.php`**

`{"id": $id, "success": 1}` upon success.
`{"id": $id, "success": 0, "error": "Could not delete user."}` upon failure.

Comment: So, what does the console show for `console.log(data.success);`? "doesn't seems to be working" is not a useful error description.

Comment: What is `delete.php` _really_ returning (with the ID substituted)?

Comment: What you have should work just fine assuming $id is numeric. Try instead `console.log(arguments)` to get more information.

Comment: Have you tried console.log(data) ??

Comment: @FelixKling: It's blank.

Comment: if (data) do not exist? Why don't you check that?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: "apologizes if the question seems logical?" you're right, most of the questions don't make sense these days...

Comment: Probably worth noting that console.log (annoyingly) isn't supported  on IE.

Comment: Check the network tab (in Chrome, or the equivalent in your browser) and see what delete.php is actually returning. It'll likely be returning something that isn't valid JSON.

Comment: I can see in Chrome's Dev tools' "Network" tab that the data is being returned from `delete.php`.

Comment: @Toddish: `{'id' : 2, 'success' : 1}` is being returned.

Comment: @Rafay Is it being returned with a 200 status code? The success callback wont fire if it returns an error code.

Comment: @DaveRandom: `Status Code:200 OK` with a green icon. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: @Rafay as DaveRandom said, you can try putting a console.log inside a .fail() to check this is not the problem

Comment: What's the result of console.log(data) then?

Comment: I use this variable data.responseText not data ?

Comment: @Rafay: Single quotes are not valid JSON. You must use double quotes. Use `json_encode` to create proper JSON.

Comment: @Rafay that is invalid JSON, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON isn't valid:

```
{'id' : 2, 'success' : 1}
```

It should have double quotes:

```
{"id" : 2, "success" : 1}
```

Based on that I think you're manually building the JSON string, I would suggest using `json_encode()` instead:

```
$result = new stdClass;
$result->id = 2;
$result->success = 1;

echo json_encode($result);
```

Outputs

```
{"id":2,"success":1}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm just getting into AJAX, and therefore was unaware. This works.

Comment: @Rafay: This has nothing to do with Ajax, just how JSON is formatted.